# Script to have Forms send an email w/ a Control Number upon "Submit"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm really new to writing scripts and am looking for some help.

I created a Google Form track important memorandum to Command level executives.  When a memo is written, the writer fills out the Google Form, and upon submitting, a script emails the writer a control number (which is found in column A) to include on the top of the memorandum form.

The form asks for:  Memo writers name (col B), date of memo (Col C), Memo writers email (Col D), and who the memo is addressed to (Col E).

Column A will be the control numbers, pre-filled in.  The email address of the memo writer is pulled from column D.

Can anyone come up with something to make this happen, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much, in advance!

Comment: You will need to at least start writing some code, and then if you get an error or unexpected result, then search for similar posts.  A good question includes some code,and an explanation of what you have tried, and what line of code is failing.  And you should include logging results.  Please read the troubleshooting guide.  [Link to troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: As for some direction, pre-fill the form, check your url parameters for which one controls then control number, and then mail merge a link to the form with the parameter set to the control number.